# Do I have to compile SDL2_mixer myself?

Tags: package-management, sdl

I want to get the package SDL_mixer to use in a game I am making, but from what I've seen there are only versions compatible with SDL 1.2. Did I overlook something or will I have to compile the SDL 2.0 version myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There it a package named `libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0` in the package repository which should be exactly what you are looking for. You will also need the package `libsdl2-mixer-dev` in order to compile against the headers of `SDL2_mixer`.

Note: You didn't specify which version of Ubuntu you are using so I checked on my current system (Ubuntu 14.04 trusty). Older versions of Ubuntu (such as Ubuntu 12.04 precise) do not include these packages. In that case you'll either have to compile from source or upgrade your system.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly :D I'll vote it as the correct answer once the site stops restricting me due to the time limit :P